# Some queries about initiation into Vadakalai Sri Vaishnavism

Tags: sri-vaishnava, initiation

How can a Macedonian national initiate into a Vadakalai mutt? And do initiates get a new name which will be in Vaishnava spirit, related to Vishnu and Lakshmi or this name stays?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88525/discussion-on-question-by-arnea-haseljic-some-queries-about-initiation-into-vada).